# [Codeigniter]Integer value for column `col_value` is incorrect

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-2

Tried below query with codeigniter.

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_common` (`menu_name`, `menu_url`, `parent_menu_id`, `col_value`, `table_nm`, `post_type`) VALUES ('Art', 'art', '3', '', 'tbl_pages', 'Page')
```

Error occure while executing above query:-Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'col_value' at row 1

Answer (score 1):

You have to set default value for `col_value` in database.

Ex : `col_value` = '0'

OR

```
INSERT INTO tbl_common (menu_name, menu_url, parent_menu_id, col_value, table_nm, post_type) VALUES ('Art', 'art', '3', '0', 'tbl_pages', 'Page')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since its look integer value, you cannot set as empty. You need to give either default value while creating DB structure or set some value while inserting. You can modify your existing structure as below.

Alter default schema with default value:-

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_common alter column col_value set DEFAULT 0;
```

If you don't want to insert value for `col_value` then try with below query:-

```
INSERT INTO tbl_common (menu_name, menu_url, parent_menu_id, table_nm, post_type) VALUES ('Art', 'art', '3', 'tbl_pages', 'Page');
```

If you want to insert value for `col_value` then try with below.

```
 INSERT INTO tbl_common (menu_name, menu_url, parent_menu_id, table_nm, post_type,col_value) VALUES ('Art', 'art', '3', 'tbl_pages', 'Page','5');
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your table datatypes are correct

menu_name  VARCHAR(20)
menu_url VARCHAR(30) 
parent_menu_id INT
col_value  VARCHAR(20)
table_nm VARCHAR(20)
post_type VARCHAR(20)

if you sent any empty values in to table please set as NULL;

```
$input = array('menu_name'=>'Art','menu_name'=>'art','parent_menu_id'=>3,'col_value'=>'','table_nm'=>'tbl_pages','post_type'=>'Page'); 
if($this->db->insert('table_name',$input))
{
    return true;
}
```